# Good books or online resources for learning Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What I found so far are some online resources like this:

http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/java-hibernate.htm (GER)

https://www.hibernate.org/5.html (Hibernate Docs)

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

http://www.manning.com/bauer2/chapter2.pdf (Sample chapter of Java Persistence with Hibernate)

http://www.wenzlaff.de/hibernate.html (GER)

So thats a good way to start but i wonder if you can recommand any good books for learning Hibernate, or maybe you know some other very good online resource for learning it?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96729/what-are-the-best-books-for-hibernate-jpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/) is the second edition of "Hibernate in Action". They changed the name since they now provide JPA examples as well as Hibernate.

[High-Performance Java Persistence](https://vladmihalcea.com/books/high-performance-java-persistence/) is also worth reading since it explains which Hibernate features are efficient and which you should stay out of.

Comment: excellent book - covers both native Hibernate, and JPA using Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks, i thought Java Persistence With Hibernate 1st Edition is different from Hibernate in Action

Answer (score 2):

**Hibernate in Action** by Christian Bauer and Gavin King

Its slightly out of date, but is an excellent introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Visit [www.flazx.com](http://www.flazx.com/search.php?p=hibernate&submit=Search). I guess Professional Hibernate (Programmer to Programmer) would be a nice selection

Answer (score 1):

These are some links I have bookmarked:

- [http://www.laliluna.de](http://www.laliluna.de/struts-hibernate-integration-tutorial-en.html)
- [Hibernate Basics](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3559931)

However, in my opinion Java Persistence with Hibernate definitely worths the money and time to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching on [www.scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com/)