# Java Hibernate: How to?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a demo from our instructor about how Hibernate works. But I'm completly lost. I can't find my way trough all the pages: Dao, Eo, Service, Vo, Action and Model.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Google->hibernate java tutorial...

Comment: @user440336 not everything that pops up when you google something is good. Asking for a good tutorial is a valid request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining the workings of hibernate is way beyond the scope of this site.

I'd recommend to consult the [QuickStart Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/), especially the sections about annotation usage [in plain hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-annotations.html) or [using JPA with hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html) (depending on which version you are using, hibernate-core or hibernate-entitymanager).

I'd also recommend to read a (current) book about hibernate. There are several questions here regarding hibernate books, here is the most current one I could find: [Good books or online resources for learning Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824214/good-books-or-online-resources-for-learning-hibernate)

And here are some hibernate-independent definitions of the objects and patterns you mentioned:

- [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) (`DAO`)
- [Value Object / Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (`VO`, `DTO`)
- [Service Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_layer)
- [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) (for the `Model` part)

I have never heard of `EO`, and `Action` is at least an ambiguous term: it may however mean the controller in MVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did use the tutorial you gave on using JPA with hibernate. 
But now I can't seem to find a great tutorial on how to create a database. It's because I don't really know what I'm looking for. The point is that I figure out how it works to create a database and then check it out with DbVisualizer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a native [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/)

Don't hurry anywhere and put effort if you really want to learn the technology.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for "[hibernate tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hibernate+tutorial)" on this server. It finds many great links like:

- [Hibernate Getting Started](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/)
- [Java Hibernate Tutorial](http://vimeo.com/12191072) on Vimeo

Comment: The first link just leads to the current version of the second (outdated) link. The problem with googling is that it often returns crap. The current link of the quickstart guide is: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/